# Write to textfile and keep it local to the programs .exe

Tags: vb.net

I have a support program i made for my dad, it basically lets him send me some text and a screenshot of a technical issue he is having and emails it to me using GMAIL SMTP.  This program works absolutely fine until i changed my gmail password.

I now want to improve this app and create a settings form where my dad can change the settings for gmail.  I figured out how to read and write to a text file but want to know if there is a way to house a textfile local to the .exe and not place the text file somewhere on his computer.  Right now im doing this to write to a textfile:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Redirection\dnapoli\desktop\test3.txt"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, False)

            objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Text written to file")

        Else

            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

        End If

    End Sub
```

I would much rather to embed this textfile inside of the textfile, so i guess you could say it could hold the text file in memory, is there any way to do that?

Thanks Plutonix for the help, found the below link which solved my issue:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/108352-how-to-use-mysettings-in-vbnet/

Comment: `My.Settings` is probably what you are looking for,  read the info and save it for use each time the app runs until he/you change them again.

Comment: You cannot modify the exe on his computer by adding settings to it. You must save either in the registry or a file on the computer.

Comment: Plutonix, thanks!!!  I used the below link for examples:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/108352-how-to-use-mysettings-in-vbnet/

Comment: you can answer your own question with the relevant code for the next person - better than a link to elsewhere